# Is there a systematic method to decompose this?

Tags: systems-of-equations, quintics

Suppose that
$$x^5+ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e=0$$
with coef.. all integers, decompose as follows
$$(x^2+Ax+B)(x^3+Cx^2+Dx+E)=0$$
which leads to the following system
$$
    \begin{cases}
      C+A = a\\
      D+AC+B = b\\
      E+AD+BC=c\\
      AE+BD=d\\
      BE=e
    \end{cases} 
$$
$$
    \begin{cases}
      C =A- a\\
      D+A(A-a)+B = b\\
      e/B+AD+B(A-a)=c\\
      A(e/B)+BD=d\\
      E=e/B
    \end{cases} 
$$
$$
    \begin{cases}
      C =A- a\\
      A^2-aA+B+D - b=0\\
      (A-a)B^2+(AD-c)B+e=0\\
      DB^2-dB+Ae=0\\
      E=e/B
    \end{cases} 
$$
$$A_{1,2}=\frac{a\pm\sqrt{a^2-4(B+D-b)}}{2}$$
$$B_{1,2}=\frac{(AD-c)\pm\sqrt{(AD-c)^2-4(A-a)e}}{2(A-a)}$$
$$B_{1,2}=\frac{d\pm\sqrt{d^2-4ADe}}{2D}$$

How can you go on from there?
Is it worth the attempt?

Comment: Maybe a *quintic* computer would be more useful.

Comment: Apparently you have a good idea. However you should know that  overcoming the difficulty to get to a resultant of the system is not worth it because it will lead you to the same equation from the beginning.

Comment: Possible, method exist for solvable quintics by extension field, Wolfram-example: `Factor[12 - 5 x + x^5, 
 Extension -> Cos[1/5 ArcCos[3/121 Sqrt[5/11 (6115 + 2764 Sqrt[5])]]]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you have heard that there is no method to solve algebraic equations of degree higher than 4. If your method would work it would allow to solvve equations of 5the degree.
you can find one  zero point x0  by newtons method for example, and than divide by(x-x0) also with integer coefficients it is often easy to find integer solutions, if the exist.